# relation between front-end functions and server routes in node.js

Tags: node.js

Inexperienced with nodejs style programming, I'm looking at an open-source node.js app that has routes with the same paths in both the front-end main.js file and the routes.js file, as you see below. I'm assuming that when the function in main.js file gets called it triggers the route in routes.js, however, I can't figure out what if anything is getting passed from main.js to routes.js as a callback.

main.js

```
$.get('/ip', function (data) {

    fp.val(fingerprint);
    userId.val(md5(fingerprint + data.ip));
  });
```

routes.js

```
    app.get('/ip', function (req, res) {
    res.json({
      ip: req.connection.remoteAddress
    });
  });
```

Comment: Use `res.send()` to send back data with can be accessed as `data` in your callback in `main.js`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing node-specific about the frontend script, it's just using [jQuery.get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) to get the document at a given URL.

On the server-side, it looks like the app is using Express (or something like it) which modifies the `.send()` method of the response to allow sending arbitrary objects. When you `send` and object, Express JSON encodes it (using `JSON.stringify(object)` and sets the Content-Type header of the response to `application/json`. This content-type header is what tells jQuery to automatically parse the JSON response back into an object in the browser.

So there is no callback being passed from main.js to routes.js, it's just a bog-standard web request that sends JSON data back to the client.